# SQL Server linked-server supplied inconsistent metadata for a column

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, openquery

I've encountered a problem executing a T-SQL statement (inserting and updating) on linked Oracle servers when executing the query twice.

The first execution works like a charm, but when trying a second time, I get this error:

> The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "Linked_Server" supplied inconsistent metadata. An extra column was supplied during execution that was not found at compile time.

I've already looked it up and tried several approaches:

- Use of openquery instead of original statement as suggested here: [MSSQL Linked Server error: The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server supplied inconsistent metadata for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658253/mssql-linked-server-error-the-ole-db-provider-oraoledb-oracle-for-linked-serv)
- Use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end of original statement as well as on the openquery statement as suggested here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275605/linked-server-throws-metadata-error or here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/98208/linked-server-throws-metadata-error.html

One thing I've encountered is when using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` the statement is infinite and I had to cancel it manually when executing the query the 2nd time.

Original statement:

```
declare @insert_cmd varchar(3000) = dbo.substringProc('
insert into LINKED_SERVER.TABLE (E_KNZ_NR, E_KNZZTRH_PERIODE_DAT, E_KNZZTRH_IST_WT, E_KNZZTRH_ERSTERF_TS) 
select
    id_dwh_knz,
    monitor_dat,
    monitor_wert,
    SYSDATETIME()
from temp_nes_kennzahl zr
left outer join (
    select 
        E_KNZ_NR,
        periode_dat=cast(E_KNZZTRH_PERIODE_DAT as date),
        E_KNZZTRH_IST_WT
    from LINKED_SERVER2.TABLE
) dwh_zr 
    on zr.id_dwh_knz  = dwh_zr.E_KNZ_NR
    and zr.monitor_dat = dwh_zr.periode_dat
where dwh_zr.periode_dat is null
order by monitor_dat asc, id_dwh_knz asc ') -- OPTION (RECOMPILE)

exec (@insert_cmd);
```

Statement with openquery:

```
declare @insert_cmd varchar(3000) = dbo.substringProc('
insert into openquery (LINKED_SERVER, ''SELECT E_KNZ_NR, E_KNZZTRH_PERIODE_DAT, E_KNZZTRH_IST_WT, E_KNZZTRH_ERSTERF_TS  FROM  LINKED_SERVER.TABLE'')
select
    id_dwh_knz,
    monitor_dat,
    monitor_wert,
    SYSDATETIME()
from temp_nes_kennzahl zr
left outer join (
    select * from openquery (LINKED_SERVER2,''SELECT E_KNZ_NR,CAST(E_KNZZTRH_PERIODE_DAT as DATE) AS periode_dat,E_KNZZTRH_IST_WT FROM LINKED_SERVER2.TABLE'')
) dwh_zr 
    on zr.id_dwh_knz  = dwh_zr.E_KNZ_NR
    and zr.monitor_dat = dwh_zr.periode_dat
where dwh_zr.periode_dat is null
order by monitor_dat asc, id_dwh_knz asc') -- OPTION (RECOMPILE)

exec (@insert_cmd);
```

(The 'substringProc' is just a helper method to retrieve the related user/database for production or test environment and 'dwh' stands for the datawarehouse at the linked oracle server)

Would be nice if someone got a solution for that, since I'm struggling with this error for quite a long time and both of the queries work - but only once. I've also read that there might be a problem with the execution plan stored in the cache but I have no clue how to workaround such an issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in my case (upgrade sql2016->2019 oracle driver 12->19), the execution time increased from a few seconds to 20 minutes  (with option recompile);

After rolling back the driver version (to 12), the error did not disappear.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275605/linked-server-throws-metadata-error